# Intermodule dependency in ant

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I am using Ant 1.8

I have multiple modules in intelliJ IDEA. Each module has a build.xml and currently i need to browse till build.xml of that file and run ant for every module. 
e.g. module B's build success depends on whether module A's build was successful.

Now, i want to update this process. It will be great if an option exists wherein i can write a single build process which will first build distribution for module A and then while building distribution for B, it will be checked if build for module A is successful.

Is there any way using current Ant mechanism. i could see something similar in ivy but i cant use it in my project.

Please suggest an approach using basic Ant features.

Comment: Why can't you use ivy? It solves this problem nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [subant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) task in ANT is the most flexible way to invoke a multi-module build, for example:

```
<project name="parent" default="build">

    <target name="build">
        <subant>
            <filelist dir=".">
                <file name="moduleA/build.xml"/>
                <file name="moduleB/build.xml"/>
            </filelist>
            <target name="clean"/>
            <target name="build"/>
        </subant>
    </target>

</project>
```

Project structure

```
|-- build.xml
|-- moduleA
|   `-- build.xml
`-- moduleB
    `-- build.xml
```

**Note:**

In my opinion the most powerful way to use this task is to combine it with the [buildlist](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html) task from Apache ivy. Let the ivy inter-module dependency declarations automatically determine the module build order.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark!! 
Your answer helped me a lot.

In addition to above answer I would like to add details, if properties are being loaded from properties file.

**Project Structure:**

|-- build.xml
|-- ProjectOne
    -- build.xml
    -- antbuilds.properties
|-- ProjectTwo
    -- build.xml
    -- antbuilds.properties

**Common ANT build file:**

```
<project name="Parent" default="all">
<target name="ProjectOne">
    <subant>
        <property file="ProjectOne/antbuilds.properties"/>
        <filelist dir=".">
            <file name="ProjectOne/build.xml"/>
        </filelist>
        <target name="deploy"/>
    </subant>
</target>
<target name="ProjectTwo">
    <subant>
        <property file="ProjectTwo/antbuilds.properties"/>
        <filelist dir=".">
            <file name="ProjectTwo/build.xml"/>
        </filelist>
        <target name="deploy"/>
    </subant>
</target>
<target name="all" depends="ProjectOne, ProjectTwo">
</target>
```